# How to do multiple actions in java try catch?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a page once user login, based on the business logic, it displays either of three actions dynamically.

1. It displays 'Add' Link - So i can click on it and do some add logic.
   (OR)
2. It Disables 'Add' button and says no user can be added more - If so, then i need to check some message is displayed.
   (OR)
3. It displays 'Link New' button - So i can click on it and do some linking new user logic.

Instead of writing each case separately, how can i achieve in one base logic something in try catch like below

```
try {
    // do the 'Add' link logic
} catch (Exception e) {
    // (OR) do verify the 'Add' link is disabled and check the error message is displayed
} catch (Exception e) {
    // (OR) do the 'Link New' button logic
}
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Exceptions are to handle errors. Don't use them for flow control and/or handling your business logic routing.

Comment: Why would you implement this using exceptions?

Comment: You should not be using Exceptions in this manner. I think you need an `if-statement`.

Comment: You shouldn't use catch blocks for your normal logic, exceptions are _exceptional_, hence the name. Just implement your methods properly, let them return something and work with that.

Comment: Because, this is one single case for me, based on same user login. When i login with this user, this screen behaves dynamically based on some business logic and i would not know when this will occur. So i need to do identify the logged in state dynamically. If this is not the right approach, please suggest a best way to identify it?

Comment: Well, you need to parse the page and identify it, how you do that, is up to you, I'm afraid. But for your states, you'd probably use an enum (at least I would do that) - the thing is: There are so many ways to implement it and you chose the least fitting one in my opinion. Exceptions are for handling errors, not for your common business logic :/

Comment: I understand that try/catch is not a solution, that is why i posted my question here to get some help.

Comment: you should describe the conditions of each case better, so anybody can provide a specific answer.. if it is based on database state, you need to make some selects to determine what should be displayed on page. If it depends on other systems, maybe you need to make some rest or soap or other requests to that system. If you can evaluate the conditions in your app, if-else statements should be enough.

Comment: Yes, i get it. This is based on a condition that only 5 users can be add/linked, once reached 5, no more can be linked or added. So i guess i need to do a check with API call and count the associated users. Based on the count i can decide. So thanks for the help, atleast it points me a path to proceed.

Comment: You can use findElements to check for your conditions... you'll need to first use a webdriverwait to check that the login has occurred.  (If this is done via JS... if a standard page-load happens, you won't need it.)  findElements will return an array whose count will be zero if the element is not found.   You can use an XPATH to target each of the conditions and set a variable you can case/switch on accordingly.  (though you may need to check disabled state for 1st two) This would avoid having a complicated try/catch where the order of thrown exceptions can sometimes be odd.

Answer (score 1):

Checking actions by handling exceptions is anti-pattern. Exceptions are used to handle errors, and is this case different system behaviour is expected behaviour.

I suggest to implement your logic, using if else, like

```js
List<WebElement> addButtons = driver.findElements(new By.ByCssSelector(selector);
boolean buttonIsEnabled = !addButtons.isEmpty() && addButtons.get(0).isEnabled(); // this code can be different in your case, based on element implementation

if(!addButtons.isEmpty() && buttonIsEnabled) {
// It displays 'Add' Link - So i can click on it and do some add logic
} else if (!addButtons.isEmpty()) {
// It Disables 'Add' button and says no user can be added more - If so, then i need to check some message is displayed.
} else {
// It displays 'Link New' button - So i can click on it and do some linking new user logic.
}
```

So in this case you would achieve all your logic in one case without catching anything and by checking elements proper states.